# Blender API (bpy) and socket server

Tags: python, sockets, python-multithreading, blender, bpy

I am running blender with a python file via shell like this
`./blender visualizer.blend -P Visualizer.py`
in my python file I have a socket server, that receives a list and loops over the list to create meshes accordingly.
Now the problem is I have to use `threading` so that blender doesn't freeze because otherwise blender's window won't even show.
but from the socket thread as it appears I can not create meshes as it crashes my blender without throwing any exception. I have tried `multiprocessing` as well and it freezes blender. 
now does anybody has any idea how to have socket server receive data and create meshes without freezing blender?

```
def socket_server(*args):
    HOST = '127.0.0.1'
    PORT = 12345
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, True)
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen(5)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    while 1:
        data = conn.recv(16384)
        if not data:
            break
        //creates mesh here
        conn.send(b'ok')
        time.sleep(1.0)

    conn.close()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        t = Thread(None, socket_server)#crashes
        t.start()

        # socket_server() #freezes

        # worker = mp.Process(target=socket_server()) #freezes
        # worker.daemon = True
        # worker.start()


    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
```

Comment: blender 2.82a, mac OS Mojave

Answer (score 1):

On blender API docs it clearly warns you not to use threading at all.

You can Create Operator and run it with timer event.
with timer event you can poll network messages from socket and perform any action.

Answer (score 0):

I came to realize that blender needs time to finish drawing an object before asking it to draw another one. so all I had to do was to put `time.sleep(1)` in my loop for creating objects.